# Archiving each string using by looping through an array

Tags: c#, loops, dotnetzip

I am currently making a piece of software that will allow the user to enter up to 6 directories, each directory is saved as a string (within an array) the loop is then meant to check through the array and any that are not null i.e. actually have a directory assigned are meant to be zipped into their own archive. This is the code I have so far.

```
        private void ZipIt()
        {
        int nxtFileNum = 0;
        string Destination = @"C:\tmpZip" + nxtFileNum + ".zip";
        // Check all fields, check if empty, if not save to Selection array
        // Seems a inefficient - Possibly loop through Text box control type and collect?
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tboxSelect1.Text) == false) { BckupArray[0] = tboxSelect1.Text; };
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tboxSelect2.Text) == false) { BckupArray[1] = tboxSelect2.Text; };
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tboxSelect3.Text) == false) { BckupArray[2] = tboxSelect3.Text; };
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tboxSelect4.Text) == false) { BckupArray[3] = tboxSelect4.Text; };
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tboxSelect5.Text) == false) { BckupArray[4] = tboxSelect5.Text; };
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tboxSelect6.Text) == false) { BckupArray[5] = tboxSelect6.Text; };

        // Create a new ZipFile entity and then loop through each array member, checking if
        // it has an assigned value, if so compress it, if not, skip it.
        using (ZipFile ZipIt = new ZipFile())
        {
            nxtFileNum++;
            foreach (String q in BckupArray)
            {
                if (q != null)
                {
                    ZipIt.AddDirectory(q);
                    ZipIt.Comment = "This archive was created at " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
                    ZipIt.Save(Destination);
                }
            }
        }        
    }
```

What I am trying to get this to do is save the first user given location to tmpZip0.7z, the second to tmpZip1.7z and so on however at the moment all it is doing is adding each directory to tmpZip0.zip.

---

Also as a side note, how would I get it to name each archive after the directory selected to be archived?

I am currently using DotNetZip (Ionic.Zip) dll.

I hope I gave enough information guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch some stuff:

```
foreach (String q in BckupArray)
{
    nxtFileNum++;
    if (q != null)
    {
        using (ZipFile ZipIt = new ZipFile())
        {
            string Destination = @"C:\tmpZip" + nxtFileNum + ".zip";
            ZipIt.AddDirectory(q);
            ZipIt.Comment = "This archive was created at " + 
                            System.DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
            ZipIt.Save(Destination);
        }
    }
}
```

Reasons:

1. The string `Destination` is fixed after you created it. It doesn't change, just because you increment `nxtFileNum`.
2. You created only one `ZipFile` and you incremented `nxtFileNum` only once, because the those were outside of your `foreach` loop
3. Putting the part that creates the ZipFile into the `if` makes sure an instance is only created if it is really used.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *can* do this with:

```
var strings = Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                      .Select(x => x.Text)
                      .Where(text => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                      .ToList();

using (ZipFile ZipIt = new ZipFile())
{
    nxtFileNum++;
    string comment = string.Format("This archive was created at {0:G}",
                                   DateTime.Now);
    foreach (string directory in strings)
    {
        ZipIt.AddDirectory(directory);
        ZipIt.Comment = comment;
        ZipIt.Save(Destination + "." + nxtFileNum);
    }
}
```

That will obviously pull *all* the textboxes though. An alternative is to have a collection of type `List<TextBox>` or something similar instead of the six different variables.

Note that that will *always* create .1, .2, .3 etc even if the user didn't specify the first three names. Let me know if you want to be absolutely faithful to the positioning the user gave.

It's not clear to me that you should really be reusing the same `ZipFile` object, by the way. I'd expect this to be more appropriate:

```
string comment = string.Format("This archive was created at {0:G}",
                               DateTime.Now);
int fileIndex = 0;
foreach (string directory in strings)
{
    fileIndex++;
    using (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile())
    {
        zipFile.AddDirectory(directory);
        zipFile.Comment = comment;
        zipFile.Save(Destination + "." + fileIndex);
    }
}
```

(Note how I've renamed the variables to be more conventional, by the way - variables typically start with a lower case letter.)

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much, however after running this amended code and clicking on the button set to launch, it doesn't do anything. I like the cycling through code you added in there for getting the values from the text boxes, that was going to be my next search around the web :D